# How to add more query on to the end of an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to pass part of the query through as a parameter of a method.

```
public IEnumerable<ServiceModel> Get(/*What would the type be*/ rightQuery)
{
    IEnumerable<EntityModel> leftQuery = repository.GetAll;
    // the query appending might look something like this: 
    var outcomeBeforeMapping = leftQuery.rightQuery;

    // ...rest is not important
}
```

The call might look like this:

```
service.Get((query) => query.OrderByDescending(project => project.SortOrder));
```

How do i go about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean ```Func<IQueryable<ServiceModel>,IQueryable<ServiceModel>> rightQuery```?

Comment: In no way do i mean IQueryable. No. Thanks though :)

Comment: ah, IEnumerable, IQueryable, who cares :) Hope you solved your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a `Func<IEnumerable<ServiceModel>, IEnumerable<ServiceModel>>` - in other words, "Given one query, I'll give you another."

```
public IEnumerable<ServiceModel> Get(
    Func<IEnumerable<ServiceModel>,  IEnumerable<ServiceModel>> transform)
{
    IEnumerable<EntityModel> leftQuery = repository.GetAll;
    var outcomeBeforeMapping = transform(leftQuery);
    ...
}
```

You should consider using `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` for this if you're using EF etc, to allow the transformation to affect the SQL rather than only being applied locally.

You should also consider simply separating out the first part of your operation from the second - allow a user to call `GetAll()`, do what they want, then pass the result back into a second method.

Comment: Why not IQueryable<> ?

Comment: @tym32167: Well the OP doesn't *have* an `IQueryable<T>` in their code at the moment. But I'm mentioning that option in an edit.

Comment: I'm not using Entity framework, it's just a collection of objects.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. (offtop: OMG, He answered me, wow! Thank you for your book, it blows my mind:))